# If $S_k = 1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$, then how can I find $S_5+S_7$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Defining $S_k = 1^k+2^k+3^k+\cdots+n^k$, how can I find what $S_5+S_7$ is equal to?

I tried finding $S_5$ and $S_7$ by first finding $S_4$ (because I already know $S_1$, $S_2$, and $S_3$), and then $S_5$, $S_6$, and finally $S_7$, but Jesus, it's so many things to keep track of that I get really lost.

Is there an easier way to deal with those two to make then appear as something I already know?

Comment: Lots of potential ideas on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_powers) [This one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) in particular stands out to me, on Faulhaber's formula.

Comment: What is $n$ here?

Comment: I don't understand the notation.  What, say, is $S_1$?

Comment: $n$ is the $n$th integer and $S_1 = 1^1+2^1+3^1+...+n^1 = 1+2+3+...+n$

Comment: So $S_k$ is a function of $n$?  But then $S_k$ is a polynomial of degree $k+1$ in $n$ so $S_5+S_7$ is a polynomial of degree $8$ in $n$.  Is that what you intended?  I mean, it turns out not to be a terrible polynomial of degree $8$, especially if you recall that $S_{2n+1}$ can be expressed using $S_1$.  As a prior comment mentioned, this is well expressed via Faulhaber's formulas.

Comment: Yeah, it would be a function of n, n integer, but I only defined $S_k$ as a shorthand to say "What is the sum of the first n integers to the $k$th power" because I thought it would be easier (and quicker) to write what I wanted to find

Oh, okie, I'll try looking at Faulhaber`s formulas, that sure would help me, I think

Comment: As alternative, you could simply compute $S_5(n)+S_7(n)$ for modest $n$.  You might then be able to spot the pattern...it's simple enough, but I'm not sure it is so easy to spot.  And once you spot it you still have to prove it.

Comment: [Sums of $5$th and $7$th powers of natural numbers: $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^5+i^7=2\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^ni\right)^4$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2568157/sums-of-5th-and-7th-powers-of-natural-numbers-sum-limits-i-1n-i5i7)

Comment: "Jesus" is not a swear word.  Flagged for bigotry.

Comment: I wasn't swearing, I was just impressed by the amount of work I had to do, and "Jesus" can be used as an interjection for that kind of surprise, so I wasn't swearing at all (here's a site which bases what I'm talking about https://englobe.hypotheses.org/271)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is:
$$S_5+S_7=1^5+\cdots+n_1^5+1^7+\cdots+n_2^7=\frac{2n_1^6+6n_1^5+5n_1^4-n_1^2}{12}+\frac{3n_2^8+12n_2^7+14n_2^6-7n_2^4+2n_2^2}{24}=\frac{4n_1^6+12n_1^5+10n_1^4 -2n_1^2+3n_2^8+12n_2^7+14n_2^6-7n_2^4+2n_2^2}{24}$$